# Laravel Sanctum returns 401

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I try to access my Laraval API from my Vue SPA but everytime I do a request I get a 401 Unauthorized. I have tried the answers from multiple SO questions but nothing works.

- I added the `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` to the API middleware.
- I set the Valet domain that I use for `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=goya.app`.
- I set the session envs:

  ```
  SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
  SESSION_LIFETIME=120
  SESSION_DOMAIN=.goya.app
  ```
- In Vue I have `axios.defaults.withCredentials` enabled.
- In the request headers I see that the XSRF token is sent.

What else can I try to fix this?

Comment: Are you making _csrf-cookie_ request before you make any API Calls ? [SPA Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-authenticating)

Comment: Ah, I did not. Is it possible to ignore this since it's a public API? Or is there a way to do the request before every call if the csrf-cookie isn't set yet?